# Is there any performance issue for websites when we send more parameters in query string

Tags: performance, url, web-applications, web

My url is as follows

`/fcgi-bin/clireports.fcgi?sfPageId=param1&sfBoxId=param2&sfPagecId=param3&sfUsername=param4&sfSession=param5&sfSubmit=param6&showSampleReport=param7&saveAndAdd=param8`

My questions is this:

Is there any performance issue when sending so many parameters in the query string ? In my case I am sending 8 parameters in the query string .

Will my website become slow because of this ?

Please enlighten me on this .

Comment: Thank you for that nice question ... this made my day ;) ... no, the amount of data, which is about 2k max. for a GET request doesn't make any difference ... even for mobile applications. I assume "clireports" is some kind of reporting script, I would be more concerned, if a certain parameter leads to longer executions/queries inside your script ...

Answer (score 1):

The performance is not about number of parameters (or just a little) but about number of bytes send.
The more data you send, the more it's costly to transfer/parse.

Remember that every browser has a hard limit on the maximum number of characters a GET request can handle. I recomment you not to use more than 255 characters to be on the safe side, but you can go higher (IE's limit is around 2000).

If you need more data, use POST.

Finally, your website will not become slow because of this. Because many other factors take much time than parsing GET request (take something like DB connection, or just php warmup)

Comment: +1 good answer. One thing about `POST`: If you really have tons of data, then maybe using `POST` over `GET` is your only solution. But the main reason to choose one over another should be the [methods' properties](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and not data size.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be any issues, might be worth doing a POST request to clean up your request a bit, but other than that you shouldn't notice any issues as far as performance...just don't exceed the "limits" that vary depending on browser